# UnsupportedOperationException when initializing LocationCallback

Tags: java, android, android-studio, location, android-location

Recently, I'm working on GPS location API, I'm try to get the current updated GPS location, but when comes to initialize the LocationCallback(), i got this error :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: can't load this type of class file
```

The snippets in the following section are try to get the LocationCallback():

```
private void createLocationCallback() {
    mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            mCurrentLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
            setLatLong(mCurrentLocation);
        }
    };
}
```

When comes to:

```
mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback()
```

It returns me the error.

After few days struggling, I found my:

```
LocationCallBack();
```

source code are empty:

```
package com.google.android.gms.location;

public class LocationCallback {
    public LocationCallback() {
    }

    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult var1) {
    }

    public void onLocationAvailability(LocationAvailability var1) {
    }
}
```

I suspect this is the root cause of the error.
I'll appreciate if anyone could help me up.

Comment: Why you need this `super.onLocationResult(locationResult);` ? Check your import, it must be `import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;`

Comment: Also when it will work, you need to check locationResult if not null and make for like in answer

Comment: did you use GoogleApiClient in your code?

Comment: No, I didn't apply any GoogleApiClient in my code. Do I have to ??

Comment: just asking, in docks of GoogleApiClient in trows UnsupportedOperationException. What about import, its same? what is your version of `com.google.maps:google-maps-services` and `com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils` and this `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location`

Comment: versions in gradle file

Comment: This is my google play service and import

    `com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0, import` `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;`, `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0`

I didn't use any `com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils`

Comment: and  google-maps-services ?

Comment: `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0` this is my version now

Comment: you have made clean and rebuild project?

Comment: Yes I did, but nothing changed

Comment: can you downgrade play-services-maps to 15.0.0 and clean and rebuild project

Comment: Yes I did, but nothing changed as well